# Laravel 5.1 - Socialite - Fetching User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-socialite

Using official [Laravel Docs 5.1 - Socialite](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication), I set my routed and edited my AuthController.

```
   public function redirectToProvider()
   {  
      return Socialite::driver('facebook')
         ->scopes(['public_profile', 'email'])->redirect();
   }
```

It works perfectly and returns 
`http://domain.dev/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQDLFlYr...`

Then I used [Laracasts' Socialite - Laravel 5.0](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/9), I tried turn my one into a proper Facebook authentication. I did everything until (*min. 12.11*, specifically) in the video. *(At 12.11 he recaps the stuff in 15 sec). This is what I am trying to do.*

---

Now, when I change my `AuthController` to:

```
  public function redirectToProvider(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request)
  {  
     return $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'));

  }
```

...and have my `AuthenticateUser class` like this:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;  (PS. I changed Authenticator to Guard)

  class AuthenticateUser {
       private $users;
       private $socialite;
       private $auth;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $users, Socialite $socialite, Guard $auth)
    {

      $this->users = $users;
      $this->socialite = $socialite;
      $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function execute($hasCode)
    {   
      // dd($hasCode) *First dd

      if ( ! $hasCode) return $this->getAuthorizationFirst();

      $user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();

      // dd($hasCode) *Second dd
      // dd($user) *Third dd
    }

    private function getAuthorizationFirst()
    {
      return $this->socialite->driver('facebook')
         ->scopes(['public_profile', 'email'])->redirect();
    } 
  }
```

*`*UserRepository is currently empty.`*

---

When I use `*First dd`, I receive `False` on the screen.

When I use `*Second dd`, I receive `True`.

When I use `*Third dd`, I receive nothing.

In all of these instances, now, I am receiving `http://domain.dev/auth/facebook?code=9329409329042`.

---

Edit:

- I added `return`and now the link includes `?code=9390249032...`, however when I use `*Third dd` - `dd($user)`, still nothing gets returned
- I managed to come until here:

  ```
      public function execute($hasCode)
  {

           dd($hasCode); // returns FALSE now     
  if ( ! $hasCode) return $this->getAuthorizationFirst();

           dd($hasCode); // returns TRUE now

      $user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();

          dd($user);  // BUT STILL RETURNS NOTHING

   }
  ```

.. and link includes `?code=9943290...`

- #### Basically, `$user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();` is the part not working/converting as dd($user) is not returning anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have forgot the return.

```
return $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'));
```

[image]

Comment: You're right. The code is working now through `execute` and `getAuthorizationFirst` and the link shows `/?code=23193291...` however, when I use `dd($user)` (*Third dd), Nothing returns